# Three steps forward after daytime amidah (with no minyon)

Tags: tefilla

Yo, I was wondering if one is required to take three steps forward upon conclusion of any of the day time amidas (or amidahim? Not too good with Hebrew grammar.).

According to the instructions of the Siddur Tehillas Hashem annotated edition, there is no mention of it in any or the weekday amidas (though it does mention to do it for maariv).

The problem with this is that various rabbis I've talked to say that you DO take three steps forward, even when there's no minyon (although they were unable to provide the source).

So, does such a custom exist? If so, where is it written?

EDIT just to clarify, I'm wondering if this applies only without a minyon because some have the custom to take 3 steps forward specifically for kedusha.

Comment: Duplicate? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57608

Comment: @Fred lol thanks, although that question is the polar opposite of mine!

Comment: It's amidos/amidot. I just looked at the Siddur, and I see what you mean, it doesn't say a word about taking 3 steps forward. Same thing by the older non annotated versions. It's a quote from Shulchan aruch harav. But in the non annotated newer versions, it adds from another source about 3 steps forwards, discussing how long you need to stay back, until kedushah or if you can't, until the chazan starts chazaras hashatz. It doesn't say it there, I can try and find the source, but if you're not with a minyan, you wait at least the time it takes to walk 4 amos

Answer (score 1):

The three steps forward are not for Kedushah. They are to end the status of Amidah, of which you are still connected to in some way while standing back three steps. The Halacha is, that instead of ending it right away we wait until Kedusha, and that if you are by yourself you should wait the time it would take to walk 4 cubits.

When we step back the three steps it is like when you back away from a high official or holy Tzaddik. But you are still in his presence until you walk back. It is this presence that we are trying to not run away from by waiting the cubits or until Kedusha.

The Tur Orach Chayim 123 says:

> סימן קכג 
>   וכורע ופוסע ג' פסיעות לאחוריו ובכריעה אחת ובעודו כורע קודם שיזקוף יטה בראשו לצד שמאלו כמי שבא ליפטר מרבו ואחר כך לימינו דאמר ריב"ל המתפלל צריך שיפסע ג' פסיעות לאחוריו ואח"כ יתן שלום ואם לא עשה כן כאילו לא התפלל ויש נוהגין לומר שלום בשמאלי ושלום בימיני עושה שלום במרומיו וכו' וראייתם מהא דאמרינן במסכת יומא משום רבי שמעיה אמרו נותן שלום בימינו ואח"כ בשמאלו פי' בימינה של שכינה שהיא כנגדו שהוא שמאלו וכ' אבי העזרי שאין לאומרה שאין פירושו שיאמר שלום בימיני וכו' אלא כשאומר עושה שלום במרומיו הופך פניו לצד שמאלו וכשיאמר והוא יעשה שלום הופך פניו לצד ימינו ובמקום שכלו ג' פסיעות יעמוד ולא יחזור מיד למקומו דאיתמר (יומא נג:) משמיה דרב מרדכי כיון שפסע ג' פסיעות לאחריו התם מיבעי ליה למיקם משל לתלמיד שנפטר מרבו שאם חוזר מיד דומה לכלב שב על קיאו שסופו הוכיח על תחילתו שלא פסע לאחוריו כדי ליפטר מרבו כיון שחוזר אליו מיד וכתב רב אלפס מבעי ליה למיקם התם עד דפתח ש"צ וכד פתח ש"צ הדר לדוכתיה ואיכא מ"ד עד דמטי ש"צ לקדושה :

And the Shulchan Aruch 123 says:

> סימן קכג
>
> {א} כורע ופוסע ג' פסיעות לאחריו בכריעה אחת ואחר שפסע ג' פסיעות בעודו כורע קודם שיזקוף כשיאמר עושה שלום במרומיו והופך פניו לצד שמאלו וכשיאמר הוא יעשה שלום עלינו הופך פניו לצד ימינו ואחר כך ישתחוה לפניו כעבד הנפטר מרבו. הגה: ונהגו לומר אחר כך יהי רצון שיבנה בית המקדש כו' כי התפלה במקום העבודה ולכן מבקשים על המקדש שנוכל לעשות עבודה ממש - דברי עצמו
>
> {ב} במקום שכלו ג' פסיעות יעמוד ולא יחזור למקומו עד שיגיע שליח ציבור לקדושה ולפחות עד שיתחיל שליח צבור להתפלל בקול רם. הגה: והשליח ציבור יעמוד כדי הילוך ד' אמות קודם שיחזור למקומו להתפלל בקול רם (תשובת הרשב''א סימן תל''ו). וכן יחיד המתפלל יעמוד במקום שכלו פסיעותיו כשיעור זה קודם שיחזור למקומו (בית יוסף בשם רבינו ירוחם וירושלמי).

And the Magen Avraham there writes:

> מג"א
>   כתב הכ"מ דאם רוצה עומד שם ואינו חוזר למקומו אבל לפי סברת י"א הטעם דבעינן ו' פסיעות עב"י ולכן צריך ג"כ לפסוע ג' פסיעות לפניו ומהאי טעמא מקפידין שלא יעבור אדם לפניהם בעוד שעומדין שם שלא להפסיק בן הו' פסיעות

Without this Magen Avraham the idea is to go back to your place, but if you take larger steps and can do it in two that shouldn't matter לכאורה. The Magen Avraham is saying, though, that there is a point to taking six steps, three back and three forward. Without this Magen Avraham the idea is to go back to your place, but if you take larger steps that shouldn't matter לכאורה.

Comment: Any idea why the instructions of the Siddur totally omitted the mention of taking three steps forward for the daytime prayers (consistently through 3 editions?) Surely they must have some reason.What is it, and moreover, what is the source for your reason?

Comment: The Siddur is giving instructions for Davenning in Shul. By Maariv, being that there is no Kedusha, we wait 4 cubits instead.

Comment: I'm confused where (outside the MA) you see any reason to go back to your place, other than if you want to sit in your chair or just get out of the guy-behind-you's place. The rule is _if_ you want to return, don't go right away. You have not brought any support for "They are to end the status of Amidah, of which you are still connected to in some way while standing back three steps."

Comment: We see that when he says, וכן יחיד המתפלל יעמוד במקום שכלו פסיעותיו כשיעור זה קודם שיחזור למקומו. He can't walk away either.

Comment: If we take three steps back at the end to recede from His presence, and take 3 steps forward at the start of the kedusha to enter His presence once more, why do we not take 3 steps back at the end of the kedusha?

Comment: @YehudaW That's not the idea of the three steps forward by Kedusha. The three steps are not for Kedusha. If you weren't praying with them and you join for Kedusha you don't take any steps. The three steps are part of ending Shmone Esrei, but we wait until Kedusha.

Comment: I thought we take 3 steps back before the amida just to have room to take 3 steps forward, since we daven in somewhat tight quarters nowadays. If so, we complete the amida when we take 3 steps back and there is no reason to take 3 steps foward to complete the amida.  Are you saying the 3 steps forward after the amida are required when davening alone?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any requirement to take three steps forward.

ואמרי משמיה דרב מרדכי מקום שכלו ג' פסיעות שם צריך ליתן שלום. ואינו צריך לחזור למקום שהתפלל וליתן שלום

"And they say in the name of Rabbi Mordecai: At the place where the three steps [back] end, there one needs to 'take leave' and does not
need to return to the place he prayed and take leave."

[Siddur Rashi, section 39](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_49492_91.pdf)

('Take leave' is my attempt to translate 'li-teyn shalom', which is some kind of a gesture of leave-taking. The custom is to bow to one's left and to one's right.)

If you look at the relevant passages in the Gemara and at the halakhot in the Rambam, you see that, at the point where people ended up at the end of the three steps back, they would remain, and would perform supplications at that place while lying face down on the floor.

(Those supplications don't correspond one-to-one to what we do today. They might have something to do with our contemporary 'nefilat appayyim' and/or with the practice of adding the personal supplication 'Elohay Neṣor' to the Amidah and/or with the recitation of the verses of supplication in u-Va le-Ṣiyyon. In any case, if they were done at the point where the three steps back ended, it would seem to preclude the notion of having to return to one's original prayer position.)