# Why six steps for Shmoneh Esreh?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, shemoneh-esrei, mishnah-berurah

In Orach Chaim Siman 123 Saif 2, SK 8, the [Mishna Berura](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=286) brings two opinions regarding the amount of steps needed before one has to say Kedusha. The Kesef Mishna holds that after one's three steps back at the end of Shmoneh Esreh, he can stand there and recite Kedusha there. The Mishna Berura then brings a Magen Avraham who says that there is an opinion that you need 6 steps and therefore one would have to walk forward to say Kedusha.

My question is two part: 1) Where does this opinion of six steps come from? What's the reason for 6 steps before Kedusha? 2) Regarding that answer, would it follow that this whole discussion only follows an Amida that has Kedusha but a Maariv Amida would not have this six steps idea?

Please cite sources.

Comment: possible dupe of 2 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57608/759 (though this seems better posed, yet possibly too broad; hmmmm....)

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm hoping that it gets across I am looking for a reason as to why 6 steps are needed as the Magen Avraham says

Answer (score 2):

1. See Bet Yosef 123, 3:

   > כתב רבינ מנוח דהני שלש פסיעות ילפינן מדכתיב ורגליהם רגל ישרה, רגליהם תרי, רגל חד; ויש אומרים שש דהא כתיב בתריה וכף רגליהם ככף רגל עגל ‏
   >
   > we learn this from their legs (=2) leg (=1) their feets (=2) as a foot (=1)
2. this verse is in Merkava of Yechezkel (1, 7)

   > וְרַגְלֵיהֶ֖ם רֶ֣גֶל יְשָׁרָ֑ה וְכַ֣ף רַגְלֵיהֶ֗ם כְּכַף֙ רֶ֣גֶל עֵ֔גֶל וְנֹ֣צְצִ֔ים כְּעֵ֖ין נְחֹ֥שֶׁת קָלָֽל׃ ‏
   >
   > concerning Chayot Hakodesh
3. The Kedusha is from Yesha'ia 6, 3:

   > ב שְׂרָפִ֨ים עֹמְדִ֤ים ׀ מִמַּ֙עַל֙ ל֔וֹ שֵׁ֧שׁ כְּנָפַ֛יִם שֵׁ֥שׁ כְּנָפַ֖יִם לְאֶחָ֑ד בִּשְׁתַּ֣יִם ׀ יְכַסֶּ֣ה פָנָ֗יו וּבִשְׁתַּ֛יִם יְכַסֶּ֥ה רַגְלָ֖יו וּבִשְׁתַּ֥יִם יְעוֹפֵֽף׃ ג ג וְקָרָ֨א זֶ֤ה אֶל־זֶה֙ וְאָמַ֔ר קָד֧וֹשׁ ׀ קָד֛וֹשׁ קָד֖וֹשׁ יְהֹוָ֣ה צְבָא֑וֹת מְלֹ֥א כׇל־הָאָ֖רֶץ כְּבוֹדֽוֹ׃  ‏
   >
   > concerning Serafim.
4. I seems effectively that the next 3 are not linked to a Tefila without Kedusha (Maariv, Yechidut). For yachid Bet Yosef at the end of siman 123 does not mention the 6 steps. The first 3 step are the only mentionned in Gemara by Rav Alexandri in name of Rabbi Yehoshua Ben Levi (Yoma 53b) and is linked to "Ose Shalom..."

   > R'Alexandri said in the name of R'Joshua B'Levi: One who prays the 'Amidah should go three steps backwards, and then recite 'peace'.

Comment: Before I accept, can you clarify as to why the next three are not connected to a Tefila without Kedusha?

Comment: @Bochur613 I am not sure but the 3 first have an independent reason, the 3 next are based only on the pasuk of Keddusha. but I am not 200% sure, I will further trying to find the accurate phrase in Bet Yosef

Comment: @Bochur613 fixed  I hope

Answer (score -1):

The Aruch HaShulchan writes in 123:3

> ובמקום שכלו השלוש פסיעות – יעמוד שם ולא יחזור תיכף למקומו. ואם עשה כן
>   – נוח לו שלא התפלל כלל. ובגמרא אמרו על זה שהוא ככלב שב על קיאו (יומא
>   נג ב), שהרי נפטר מרבו, ועתה נראה שחוזר בו ממה שהתפלל ובקש סליחה
>   ומחילה, ורוצה לחטוא עוד (ב"ח). **ולכן לא יחזור למקומו עד שיגיע שליח
>   ציבור לקדושה, דבזה הכל רואים שחוזר למקומו מפני הקדושה**
>
> Therefore, one should not go back to his place until the Shaliach Tzibbur gets to Kedusha for then everyone sees he is going back to his place for Kedusha

It seems from here that walking steps forward is linked to Kedusha.

In Aruch HaShulchan 123:4

> יש נוהגים להקפיד שבפסעו הפסיעות – לא יעבור אדם בינו לבין מקום שהתפלל. וטעם הדבר: מפני שיש אומרים דצריך ששה פסיעות, משום ד"פסיעה" לא מקרי רק כשעוקר שני רגליו. וכן נהגו חכמי צרפת. ויש להם סמך, מדכתיב בתחילת יחזקאל בחיות שבמרכבה: "ורגליהם רגל ישרה", "רגליהם" – תרי, "רגל" – חד, הוי שלוש. ואחר כך כתיב: "וכף רגליהם ככף רגל..." – הוי גם כן תלת. **ולכן חושבים השלוש פסיעות שחוזר למקומו בעת הקדושה לצירוף השלוש ראשונו**ת

Here too, it seems to follow that three steps forward is linked only to Kedusha. Therefore, when there is no Kedusha, like Maariv, one would not have to walk three steps forward after Shmoneh Esreh

Comment: "וטעם הדבר: מפני שיש אומרים דצריך ששה פסיעות, משום ד"פסיעה" לא מקרי רק כשעוקר שני רגליו" that pretty clearly applies even without Kedusha. He's just saying 'Kedusha' later on bc that's the usual time that you can go back to your seat. אורחא דמילתא נקט.